# Match list of search terms in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im creating a live search box on express and it shows 2 errors.

> (1) TypeError (2) Unhandled Promise rejection

**CODE:**

```
router. post('/search-phrasing', async (req, res) => {
        const {
            phrasing
        } = req.body;
        const

 phrasingArray = phrasing.trim().split(' ');

phrasingArray.map(async (phrasing) => {
    let suggestions = [];

    await Response.find({
        entities: {
            $regex: new RegExp(phrasing)
        }
    }).sort({
        phrasing: 'asc'
    }).then((data) => {
        if (data[0]) {
            suggestions.push({
                id: data[0]._id,
                phrasing: data[0].phrasing
            });

            res.send(suggestions);
        }
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
});
```

Comment: Yes it's a mongoose. i tried placing outsinde .map() after .catch(), and still prints an error. I'm trying to request an array of response - a phrasing on my database.. Where in it has at matched entities which is an array from a user's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt to loop async functions this way as it is not required, and certainly don't send responses in a loop. Instead you should `.map()` the list of regular expressions to [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
router.post('/search-phrasing', (req, res) => {
  const { phrasing } = req.body;

  if (phrasing == undefined || ( typeof(phrasing) != 'string' ) )  {
    console.error("phrasing is required as a string");
    return res.end(); // really should have better error handling
  }

  const phrasingArray = phrasing.trim().split(' ');

  Response.find({ entities: { $in: phrasingArray.map(e => RegExp(e)) })
    .sort('phrasing')
    .select('phrasing')
    .then(suggestions => res.send(suggestions))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator accepts an array of arguments to match. It also happens to accept regular expressions as those arguments. It's basically shorthand for the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator but always applying to the one field.

Attempting to do this otherwise is executing multiple statements with the database, awaiting various promises and attempting to construct a single response from all of that. It's simply not necessary when there are query expressions which already handle this.

Also check your input types. Don't blindly presume you supplied the required data to the POST body. Check for it being present as is shown here, otherwise you get exceptions

Comment: Solved. Thank you!